# TSQL aggregation function in CASE/WHEN condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, aggregation, case-when

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Q.FIELD_1) > 1 AND MAX(Q.FIELD_1) <> 'N/A' THEN 'VALUE_010' ELSE 'VALUE_011' END AS FIELD_1,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Q.FIELD_2) = 10 AND MAX(Q.FIELD_2) <> 'N/A' THEN 'VALUE_020' 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Q.FIELD_2) = 100 AND MAX(Q.FIELD_2) <> 'N/A' THEN 'VALUE_021'   
        ELSE 'VALUE_022' END AS FIELD_2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        A.FIELD_1,
        B.FIELD_2
    FROM TABLE_A a
    JOIN TABLE_B b
        ON a.FIELD_X = b.FIELD_Y
    GROUP BY
        A.FIELD_1,
        B.FIELD_2
) Q
```

What I want is to use aggregation functions like COUNT or MAX combined in the CASE/WHEN conditions of the select. Actually I got error: "Incorrect syntax near >". 
Is it possible or I should try different approaches?

Comment: Why not do the count(distinct ...) in the subquery?

Comment: Edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @JNevill Because I need to combine more aggregate functions in the CASE/WHEN conditions. I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you post the entire error you are getting? The query looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you have a comma after FIELD_2 in your code

```
ELSE 'VALUE_022' END AS FIELD_2,
```

Comment: Thanks but it was just a typo

Comment: You should be able to use count in a CASE statement. I tried similar code and it works.The code you provided looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you have a trailing comma in `ELSE 'VALUE_022' END AS FIELD_2,`

Otherwise try

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Q.F1 > 1 THEN 'VALUE_010' ELSE 'VALUE_011' END AS FIELD_1,
    CASE
        WHEN Q.F2 = 10 THEN 'VALUE_020' 
        WHEN Q.F2 = 100 THEN 'VALUE_021'   
        ELSE 'VALUE_022' END AS FIELD_2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT DISTINCT(A.FIELD_1) AS F1,
        COUNT DISTINCT(B.FIELD_2 AS F2
    FROM TABLE_A a
    JOIN TABLE_B b
        ON a.FIELD_X = b.FIELD_Y
    GROUP BY
        A.FIELD_1,
        B.FIELD_2
) Q
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to know if TSQL syntax allows to combine aggregate functions in the CASE/WHEN conditions directly, like for example COUNT and MAX. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT a.FIELD_1) > 1 THEN 'VALUE_010' ELSE 'VALUE_011' END AS FIELD_1
    ,CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.FIELD_2) = 10 THEN 'VALUE_020' 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.FIELD_2) = 100 THEN 'VALUE_021'   
        ELSE 'VALUE_022' END AS FIELD_2 
FROM  TABLE_A a
JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.FIELD_X = b.FIELD_Y
GROUP BY A.FIELD_1, B.FIELD_2
```